# Home lab double slit "where to get lab quality slits?" :)

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, double-slit-experiment

I purchased a small light table demo kit from thorlabs and I would like to setup a double slit demo. Thorlabs does not sell any double slits, and I am having a hard time finding a vendor that might sell a lab quality double slit aperture. I would like a 1" round disk, or even a 2", or multiple slits per disk etc. My primary concern is that it is lab quality and not consumer sorta quality.

I suspect I simply do not know the right terms to search effectively. A diy one is easy, and I have done this, but I'd like a formal lab quality adjustable, or maybe slide with a few different spacing/slit widths.

Any brand names or vendor names would be ideal.

Comment: You might be pleasantly surprised what a laser or ink jet printer can do on clear stock.

Comment: Edmund optics??

Comment: Thank you for the hints, I will try the printer diy method, interesting.

Answer (score 2):

In my lab course, we use optical equipment provided by Pasco. The diffraction slits you refer to can be found e.g. [here](https://www.pasco.com/products/lab-apparatus/light-and-optics/diffraction/os-8442).

As a caveat, the listed price is specifically for educators; you would have to speak with their sales department to see if the price is different for hobbyists.

Comment: Thanks for this link, the Pasco would have been my choice but the mounting system they use seems cumbersome for my light table.

I did find these, and with a slide holder mount I am satisfied with the overall usability. 
https://www.a3bs.com/apertures-diffraction-elements-and-filters,pg_872.html

Answer (score 0):

Thorlabs now offers [precision double slits](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=16177).